# Upgrade GoogleTest to Visual Studio 2013 with command line

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2013, command-line, upgrade, googletest

I've been attempting to automate the cloning and building of google test by using a batch script. However I can't seem to get visual studio to upgrade the solution.

I tried using the `devenv "path" /upgrade` command however it fails to upgrade the projects. The error I am getting for each of the projects is:

```
gtest_main-md.vcproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942
```

Which just defaults to the VS2015 C++ projects page. The solution also states that it does not need to be upgraded. If I open the solution in visual studio I can simply perform the one time upgrade on each project with no issue.

Is there a way to do this without having to open visual studio?